# AFNetworking and IPV6 reject with iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking, ipv6

Sent out our app through app review process and got rejected due to the ipv6 completeness issue. Our app is using AFNetworking 3.1.0 so no problem there. Our API isn't IPV6 compatible. The review is coming back with a crash that we can't reproduce as well.

I guess my first question is: 
1.) We need something quick + dirty for the weekend. Can we just create a build without having to actually support ipv6 in the backend through AFNetworking?

2.) Is there any other things we need to do with AFNetworking other than having the most updated one? Are there any code changes to make sure we support ipv6?

Comment: The application running on the iOS device needs to run on an IPv6-only network, not the server. Apple has a set of instructions for how to build an IPv6-only test network.

Comment: Make sure you are using a host name and not an IPv4 address for your server inside your app

Comment: AF 3.0.0 Added support for IPv6 to Reachability..So you need to debug app locally with IPV6 connectivity for more info refer this link https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202237

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find the code in AFNetworking:

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

Update the code to:

```
#if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 90000) || (defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 101100)
    struct sockaddr_in6 address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin6_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
#else
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
#endif
```

Update all libs if it using:

```
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I already have that in code when I sent it over for review and still came back rejected. I'm using 3.1.0 of AFNetworking so I thought there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: You can ask review team for the crash logs, we can find out the real problem with it.

Comment: @John D, does this solve your problem? look at the comment seems it did not solve your ploblem, but why you choose it to answer?

Answer (score 0):

My deployment target is still iOS7 and the AFNetworking 3.1 has the same code as accepted answer within AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m

When I put the breakpoint there then I see it goes to IPv4 part even when I test on my iPhone 6S.
I believe that this is the reason for Apple rejection of not supporting IPv6.

The code from AFNetworking uses IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED which check only deployment target but not the actual version of iOS on your device.
You can easily change it to

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_0) {
    struct sockaddr_in6 address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin6_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;

    return [self managerForAddress:&address];
  }
  else {
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;

    return [self managerForAddress:&address];
  }
```

and it will go to IPv6 code on iOS9 and newer .
I'm sending this build for review and let you know if that helped.

Comment: OK, so what happened?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that it has passed through review already many times so this workaround works fine.